# How to search SQL when words contain errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to execute a SQL command. However, the keywords may contain errors. For example, the correct command should be

```
select id from my_table where name = 'Tommy'
```

It would return 1.

However, if someone execute the following incorrect command:

```
select id from my_table where name = 'Tomyy'
```

How to change the command so that it still returns 1?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you are looking for is doing a Fuzzy Search with SQL. You can read the query posted at http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/fuzzy-string-matching-using-levenshtein-distance-sql-server.aspx, which is calculating Levenshtein Distance for fuzzy searching. You can then base on the edit distance to decide how much typos you accept in your query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Does it have SOUNDEX or similar function?

Comment: I am using MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle these, but please keep in mind this isn't the easiest of tasks. What you're looking for is a fuzzy search algorithm.

This should get you started: [Fuzzy searches in SQL Server (Redgate)](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/fuzzy-searches-sql-server/)
Code project also has some interesting options here: [Implementing phonetic name searches](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4623/Implement-Phonetic-Sounds-like-Name-Searches-wit-3)

If you're looking for an easier but more barebones solution you should look into using [SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [DIFFERENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (assuming your dbms is MSSQL). I've been playing a bit with `DIFFERENCE` and it's pretty cool what this can do out of the box.

Comment: Thank you, Jens. The Fuzzy search is difficult to understand for me. On the other hand, there are only four levels in DIFFERENCE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select id from my_table where SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('Tomyy')
```